# Как поставить шанс на выполнения запроса?

Tags: php

У меня есть запрос:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE inv SET kol=`kol`+1 where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Как поставить процент выполнения такого запроса? Например:

```
этот запрос  mysql_query("UPDATE inv SET kol=`kol`+1 where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"); выполниться с шансом в 25%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для 25% шанса:

```
$chance = mt_rand(1,4) === 1;
if($chance) {
    // тут твой код
}
```

для не фиксированного шанса:

```
function getChance($percent) {
     $rand = mt_rand(1,100);
     if($rand <= $percent) {
      return true;
     }
}
```

использовать так:

```
 $chance = 25;   // измени это значения для изменения шанса выполнения
 if(getChance($chance)) {
      // шанс исполнения этого $chance %
 }
```